# How can I enable msys UNIX paths in Code::Blocks (MinGW)?

Tags: gcc, mingw, codeblocks, msys

When I use the MinGW shell, I can use all the UNIX dev paths (such as `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`) in my GCC commands. However, if I try to tell Code::Blocks to include `/usr/local/include`, it does not recognize it. It seems that when using Code::Blocks, I am not tapping into the msys 'environment'. Is there a way I can do that? For example, I'd love to be able to commit Code::Blocks project files that target those paths and just work regardless of where someone installed MinGW.